# Enable java Applets and WebStart without using the Java Control Panel

Tags: java, java-web-start

Is there any way to enable "Java content in the browser" without ticking the check box from Java Control Panel?

I have an application, which bundles jre8 and launches an external javaws process. My app cannot start the javaws process untill I manually tick the "Enable Java content in the browser" from javacpl.

I tried to manually add the `deployment.webjava.enabled=true` (which accordingly to Oracle should be true by default) in the `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties` but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was related to a bug in Java versions prior to 8u45. A simple update to Java 8 update 45 fixed the issue.

The `deployment.webjava.enabled=true` flag is indeed true by default, just it doesn't work with a bundled (by install4j - copied) java on older versions.